# Conditional hiding/showing endpoint's swagger doc with Flask-RESTX

Tags: python, swagger, flask-restx

I am trying to conditionally hide/show an endpoint swagger doc with Flask-RESTx, I am aware of using `@api.doc(False)` to disable (as shown here [Hide endpoints in UI of Flask restful Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26142997/4437911)) however, it doesn't work with `@api.route("/register", doc=True)` will get the error -

```
kwargs["route_doc"] = self._build_doc(cls, doc)
  File "python3.9/site-packages/flask_restx/namespace.py", line 115, in _build_doc
    unshortcut_params_description(doc)
  File "/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restx/namespace.py", line 355, in unshortcut_params_description
    if "params" in data:
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

I wonder if it's possible to hide/show endpoint's swagger doc based on condition variable

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it did work with `@api.doc(True)`, however it didn't work with `@api.route("/<endpoint>", doc=True)`